# crontab expression to schedule a DAG in Apache Airflow

Tags: cron, airflow-scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

I would like to schedule a DAG in Apache Airflow that has to run daily at 8 AM EST(12 PM UTC) to 9 PM EST(1 AM UTC).

I have tried with '* 12-1 * * *' and this is not working as we are trying to schedule from 12 pm of the current day to 1 am next day.

Any alternate method also helps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out the way to give the schedule interval using crontab expression. Below expression works for the given requirement.

```
* 12-23,0-1 * * *
```

Also I am trying to run the DAG for every 15 minutes from 10th minute through 59 every hour so I modified the expression accordingly. My final expression would look something like below.

```
10-59/15 12-23,0-1 * * *
```